# C# Count decimal digits after . and before the first number

Tags: c#

I'm really new in c#, and I hope anyone can help me.
I just want to to know, if there is a easier and faster way to solve my calculations.

Example: I have 0.001, I want to Count how much 0 after the dot and before the 1 number...
Also the result is 2, because of 2x 00.

This is atm my Calc;

```
decimal test = 0.001m;
var test1 = Convert.ToString(test).Split('1');
var test2 = test1[0].Split('.');
int test3 = test2[1].Count(Char.IsDigit);
test3 = 2
```

Thanks :)

Comment: The number of integer digits can be calculated using the log10 logarithm of the number, specifically `Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(number))`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Also Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(number)) this give me -3 with my Example 0.001 Number.

Comment: @Kababum that's because 0.001 = 10^-3; that formula calculates the magnitude of a number in base 10. You'd have to do some extra checking, but I'd personally prefer doing it the math way.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: this has to be treated with care because there are no implementations of the `Math` methods that work with `decimal`, and explicitly converting to `double` can lose precision, which is precisely what you hope to avoid when using `decimal`. Unfortunately `decimal` offers no direct ways to retrieve details like the stored scale/precision or the decimal logarithm, even though it could.

Comment: @JeroenMostert there's a duplicate for this that retrieves and checks the bits

Comment: @Kababum `-1 - Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(number))` to get the number of leading zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
decimal test = 0.00007m;
Int32 c = -1;
while (test < 1) { test *= 10; c++; }
Console.WriteLine($"Zero number: {c}");
```

Output: 4

Answer (score 0):

You can count after dot using this:

test.SubString(num.IndexOf(".") + 1).Length;

Comment: Also so; test.Substring(sum.IndexOf(".") + 1).Length); < But what is "sum"?